# what is the function 'bind'?

Tags: javascript, angular, bind

I have some question about function named bind.

I am testing some public source codes implemented in Angular.
I am trying to understand what the bind function, I searched internet but can't find proper answer. Could you give some guide for this?

```
export class AppComponent {

  currentPage: number = 1;

  news: Array<any> = [];

  scrollCallback;

  constructor(private hackerNewsSerivce: HackerNewsService) {

    this.scrollCallback = this.getStories.bind(this);

   }

  getStories() {
    return this.hackerNewsSerivce.getLatestStories(this.currentPage).do(this.processData);
  }

  private processData = (news) => {
    this.currentPage++;
    this.news = this.news.concat(news.json());
  }

}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: I really wonder how you managed to not find the answer by searching the internet. What search query did you try?

Comment: I tried with angular and bind, most of time angular binding relevant results are returned. I found some bind function in the javascript, but it was not interpreted to my case. so asked

Answer (score 0):

In terms of angular, function binding is used to declare a function in component/directive and define in the scope / this.

And we use where we need like volatile

Comment: Actually, that code is for implementing infinite scrolling, now I understand a little bit about bind() function.. but... when I add that bind function exactly the way as same structure as the code above. it makes my web app blinking.. I added it in the constructor of the component where is responsible for searching into database and showing the result... could you guess what the problem might be?